# How to add a node to a linkedlist and how to make a linkedlist yourself?

Tags: java, node.js

below is the official java code for data structure homework to add node to a linkedlist and ask us to creat that linkedlist ourselves......:

```
class Node {
    double data;
    Node next;
    Node(double data) {
        this.data = data;
    }      
}

Node node = new Node(23.334);
class SortedLinkedList {
    Node head;   
    public void insert(Node node) {
        if(head == null){
            head = node;
        }
        else if (node.data < head.data) {
            head.data=node.data;
            return;
        } else { 
            Node current = head;
            // find where to insert it:
            while (current.next != null) {
                if (node.data < current.data) {
                    node.data = current.next;
                    // insert it!
                    // NEED SOME CODE
                    return;
                }
            }
            previous=current;
           current=current.next;
            // You got here and didn't insert!
            // insert it here
            // NEED SOME CODE
        }
    }

}
```

what did I miss to make it work?
Also, how could we add node to the linkedlist?
I tried

> SortedLinkedList sll =new SortedLinkedList();

however the system says

> Error: |  cannot find symbol |    symbol:   class SortedLinkedList | 
>   SortedLinkedList sll =new SortedLinkedList(); |  ^--------------^

and when I tried to add node

> sll.insert(new Node (43.221);

the system always says

> Incomplete Java expression. Restarting and clearing everything...

What is wrong and how to fix the problem in my code please? and how to create a linkedlist?

Comment: `Node node = new Node(23.334);`
This code is outside of a method or class declaration. Remove it and it should compile.

Comment: Seems like homework to me...

Comment: @MartinS to just delete it? Then how to create a linked list beside that only number of node?

Comment: You need a (main) function and create it in there.

Comment: @BoristheSpider why we can't ask our homework......?......

Comment: @YingXiong because it's _your_ homework. Not ours...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, either:

A: You are trying to execute this program from somewhere else which has a `main` method, in which case the `Node node = new Node(23.334);` line is out of place and should be removed. Also, you should add the `main` method to the example.

B: You're trying to execute this code without a `main` method. Please add a `main` method.
Or...

C: All of this code is in the `main` method. Please move all of the code except for `Node node = new Node(23.334);` out of the `main` method.

Comment: The latter point - why? If all the code were _in_ the `main` method, this would be fine.

Comment: @BoristheSpider It looks terrible.

Comment: But it would _compile_ - which it currently does not. So it's likely not the issue.

Comment: @BoristheSpider That is true. I really doubted that was the problem. I think it's really just missing the `main` method.